# Update Azure OpenAI npm Package to 2023-12-01-preview Version

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, openai-api, azure-openai

I am currently using the **azure-openai** npm package in my project with version **2023-03-15-preview**. As per the latest updates, version **2023-12-01-preview** is available and brings several improvements, including support for DALL-E 3.0 and enhanced content filtering.So, i want to update my package.

My nodejs version is 18.13 and my azure-openai version is "^0.9.4".
azure-openai package use 2023-03-15-preview.
I read that in **/node_modules/azure-openai/README.md**. This README.md file mention they are used **2023-03-15-preview/**inference.json.
Now, I want to update 2023-03-15-preview with 2023-12-01-preview.**So where can i change or update this app-version**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move to the official library, which is this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/openai

You have several demos using it accessible from the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/openai-readme?view=azure-node-preview

The other one is a fork from openai repo but not the official one.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I've started using the @azure/openai package for my implementation.